# Cant play videos

Tags: videos

I have a movies folder called movies located in site root/wp-content/movies/.
I also have a template creates in my theme called page-movies.php. And a wordpress page called movies using the page-movies.php template.

What is the correct way to display the list of movie urls in the movies folder on the movies page.

I've used a scandir() inside of A tags to display all the urls as "site.com/movies/movietitle.mp4" but I click thr link to the movie is loads nothing just a blank white page.

Is there a correct way I should be loading the list of movie urls onto a oage from a directory?

Comment: Problem solved, used full url with http in the beginning to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you movies are stored in `/wp-content/movies/` and the URLs are `site.com/movies/movietitle.mp4` then the links are pointing to the wrong place.

Change the URL's to include the `wp-content` path eg `site.com/wp-content/movies/movietitle.mp4`

Separate to your question, you could look at having your `page-movies.php` template load the links into a [video element](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/) using javascript.

Comment: Thanks Alexander. I did notice that the url is in fact not pointing to the wp-content/movies directory, youre right. So the url isbjust site.com/movies/movie.mp4. Since im on the movies page, how Can I append the wp-content/ folder before /movies folder in url. And then add the movie name to that.